# Is there a database() function in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

My question is simple in mysql I used the `database()` function to get the database name

Is there a function in SQL Server that does the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `DB_NAME()` which returns the name of the current database.

```
SELECT DB_NAME()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a function called `DB_NAME()` like

```
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DataBaseName
```

see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189753.aspx)